# webView Render process (11521) kill (OOM or update), killing application

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

My logcat shows this and the app dies.
This error does not occur on all phones, but on some.

This is a webView problem because loadData does not perform any separate action.

webView Render process (11521) kill (OOM or update) wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing application

I knew this came from webView and I've seen similar cases.

so i added but there was no change

*ps reference site
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/managing-webview?hl=ko

```
setRendererPriorityPolicy(RENDERER_PRIORITY_BOUND, true)
```

my code

```
coupangWeb.settings.apply {
                            javaScriptEnabled = true
                        }

                        coupangWeb.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener{
                            override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View) {
                                webFrame.layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams().width
                            }

                            override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View) {}
                        })

                        coupangWeb.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String): Boolean {
                                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
                                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                                holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)

                                return true
                            }
                        }
                        coupangWeb.setRendererPriorityPolicy(RENDERER_PRIORITY_BOUND, true)

                        val html =
                            "<div>" + "<script src=\"https://ads-partners.coupang.com/g.js\"></script>" +
                                    "<script>new PartnersCoupang.G({someThing});" +
                                    "</script>" + "</div>"

                        coupangWeb.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF8")
```

I changed code

```
val superSafeWebView = holder.itemView.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.coupang_web)//WebView(holder.itemView.context)
                        var safeBrowsingIsInitialized: Boolean = false

                        //superSafeWebView.webViewClient = MyRendererTrackingWebViewClient(holder.itemView)
                        val webView = holder.itemView.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.coupang_web)

                        superSafeWebView.settings.apply {
                            javaScriptEnabled = true
                        }

                        superSafeWebView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener{
                            override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View) {
                                webFrame.layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams().width
                            }

                            override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View) {}
                        })

                        superSafeWebView.webViewClient = object : MyRendererTrackingWebViewClient(holder.itemView) {
                            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String): Boolean {
                                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
                                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                                holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)

                                return true
                            }
                        }
                        superSafeWebView.setRendererPriorityPolicy(RENDERER_PRIORITY_BOUND, true)

                        val html =
                            "<div>" + "<script src=\"https://ads-partners.coupang.com/g.js\"></script>" +
                                    "<script>new PartnersCoupang.G({someThing});" +
                                    "</script>" + "</div>"


                        if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.START_SAFE_BROWSING)) {
                            WebViewCompat.startSafeBrowsing(holder.itemView.context, ValueCallback<Boolean> { success ->
                                safeBrowsingIsInitialized = true
                                if (!success) {
                                    Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Unable to initialize Safe Browsing!")
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "able ")
                                    //superSafeWebView?.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF8")
                                    superSafeWebView?.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF8", null)

                                }
                            })
                        }

open class MyRendererTrackingWebViewClient(val views: View) : WebViewClient() {
    private var mWebView: WebView? = null

    override fun onRenderProcessGone(view: WebView, detail: RenderProcessGoneDetail): Boolean {
        if (!detail.didCrash()) {
            // Renderer is killed because the system ran out of memory. The app
            // can recover gracefully by creating a new WebView instance in the
            // foreground.
            Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", ("System killed the WebView rendering process " +
                    "to reclaim memory. Recreating..."))

            mWebView?.also { webView ->
                val webViewContainer: ViewGroup = views.findViewById(R.id.coupang_web)
                webViewContainer.removeView(webView)
                webView.destroy()
                mWebView = null
            }

            return true
        }

        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "The WebView rendering process crashed!")

        return false
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either

I saw in the log that System killed the WebView rendering process " +
"to reclaim memory. Recreating....

Comment: Did you look at and follow the "Termination Handling API" section of the link you posted?

Comment: Yes I already tried it , not working